# How to create a .csv file by looping over nested dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have a dictionary (my_dict) that contains multiple dictionaries of key/value pairs (indexed by number), and I am trying to create a .csv file of the values within each dictionary such that each dictionary will have values in one row of the .csv file.

The code below is successful at printing the first dictionary with the keys as headers, and the values in the row below. I then implemented a counter (since the dictionaries are indexed by dictionary number), and this is successful at writing additional dictionary values to the next row in the file. However, I am struggling to produce a for loop that will continue to add "1" to the number until the last numbered dictionary (this varies by file, but they can contain hundreds). Is there a more efficient way to do this than copying and pasting? I know there must be but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Thanks!!!!

```
import csv
number = 1 

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    rec = my_dict[str(number)]
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(rec)
    number= number + 1
    rec = my_dict[str(number)]
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
    w.writerow(rec)
    number= number + 1
    rec = my_dict[str(number)]
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
    w.writerow(rec)
    number= number + 1
```

(etc until number is the highest dictionary number... requires re-pasting this section over and over again)

Comment: How do you know the highest dictionary number? Is it stored in a variable somewher? Or do you keep trying until `my_dict[str(number)]` raises a `KeyError`?

Comment: Also, why do you have a dict keyed with keys `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc. instead of just a list indexed with the numbers as numbers?

Comment: I am creating dictionaries from medical records, which I am parsing from text files that contain a variable numbers of records. The original functions that create the dictionaries also tell you the total number of records (i.e. the number of dictionaries) obtained from each larger text file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest possible loop is just to indent the whole repeated thing and put a `while True:` around it:

```
number = 1 

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    while True:
        rec = my_dict[str(number)]
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
        if number == 1: w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(rec)
        number= number + 1
```

That almost works—except you never exit the loop.

So, how *do* you know when you're done? Do you know the highest number in advance? If so:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    for number in range(1, highest_number + 1):
        rec = my_dict[str(number)]
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
        if number == 1: w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(rec)
```

Or do you keep going until one of the numbers isn't found in the dict? Then:

```
number = 1
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    while True:
        try:
            rec = my_dict[str(number)]
        except KeyError:
            break
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
        if number == 1: w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(rec)
        number += 1
```

Or, since your keys are all just string representations of integers, just sort the dict items as integers:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    for key, rec in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=int):
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
        if key == 1: w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(rec)
```

Whatever the rule is, it should be easy to write, but without knowing the rule, it's impossible…

---

It's worth noting that the whole point of using a `DictWriter` is that all your dicts have the same keys, so you use a single `DictWriter` instead of creating a new one for each row…

Comment: Thank you so much! I had success with the code after "So, how do you know when you're done? Do you know the highest number in advance? If so:" Very, very much appreciated  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something. Have you tried:

```
import csv
NUMBER_MAX = 100 #guessing
f = open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb')
for number in range(1,NUMBER_MAX+1):
    rec = my_dict[str(number)]
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, rec.keys())
    if number == 1:
         w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(rec)
```

Of course it is better if you can write the headder outside of the for loop. But I'll leave that to you.

Note I have not tried to run this code (there are probably typos/syntax errors in it)

Comment: Thank you all so much for the replies!!!!  I just tried the second option from @abarnert above, and this worked with success!!!  THANK YOU!!!! I appreciate all of you time and expertise as I am new to programming. The successful one was the code after "So, how do you know when you're done? Do you know the highest number in advance? If so:"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant solution using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(my_dict).to_csv('mycsvfile.csv')
```

Pandas can convert a dict of dicts into a DataFrame. The `to_csv` method then writes it to a csv. You may have to play around with parameters to get exactly what you want, such as whether to write the keys or just the values. 
With the default parameters, the first row comprises the outer keys and the inner keys will make up the first column.